# Regex to check for facebook url AND be only alphanumeric.

Tags: php, regex, facebook

I made this script that requires that the user enter a facebook url. That part works well but a user can still add special characters in the url variable, and I'm trying to prevent this.

I want the regex to only allow alphanumeric characters, dashes, and underscores. And not to allow spaces.

I tried adding [a-zA-Z0-9_] to my regex but it doesn't work.

```
<?php
$facebook_url = "http://www.facebook.com/user";

if(!preg_match('^facebook\.com\S*[a-zA-Z0-9_]*^', $facebook_url)){
//if(!preg_match('^http://(?:.*\.)?facebook\.com\S*[a-zA-Z0-9_]*^', $facebook_url)){

    echo "ummm, this is not a facebook url";

} else {

    echo "this is a facebook url";

}
?>

<br />

<a href="<?php echo $facebook_url?>" target="_blank">My Facebook</a>
```

Comment: `\S*` matches any character that is not a whitespace character. Remove it, and see if it works. You might need to adjust `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, e.g. add ``\`` or `/`, `-` (at the end), etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of couse you should remove '^' character. (This sign marks the beginning of the line)

```
preg_match('/(https?:\/\/)?([\w\.]*)facebook\.com\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)$/', $facebook_url)
```

Comment: I still want the following to be acceptable urls
http://www.facebook.com/user
www.facebook.com/user
facebook.com/user

Comment: @brewpixels I changed pattern, try again

Comment: Thanks, that works, I just changed it a little because I needed the dashes. [a-zA-Z0-9_-]

Answer (score 0):

Please remove '^' characters from the beginning and the end. Use this:

```
'facebook\.com\/[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$'
```

P.S. Underscore ('_') is also allowed in url. Without underscore:

```
'facebook\.com\/[a-zA-Z0-9]*$'
```